# NFS Server (on Ubunut 14.04) using static translation with a Windows client

Tags: nfs

I am trying to setup a NFS on a Ubuntu 14.04 system.  I am following the instructions from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-file-system.html).  I have attempted to configure the translation to use static.

The /etc/idmapd.conf configuration file is setup as the following:

```
    [General]

Verbosity = 0
Pipefs-Directory = /run/rpc_pipefs
# set your own domain here, if id differs from FQDN minus hostname
# Domain = localdomain

[Mapping]

Nobody-User = nobody
Nobody-Group = nogroup

[Translation]
Method = static

[Static]
mhickXXXXX@domain.com = mhicks
mhickXXXXX            = mhicks
```

I am able to access the NFS from windows using the mount command.  The problem seems to be the user is not correct.  If I create a file in a directory with 777 permissions the user ID and group ID are incorrect, 4294967294 or -2.  I think No-Body is -1 (I am probably wrong). I can't figured out why the translation is not working correctly.

```
drwxrwxrwx  5 mhicks     mhicks     4096 Aug 31 01:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 30 mhicks     mhicks     4096 Aug 30 17:41 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 4294967294 4294967294    0 Aug 31 01:02 New Text Document.txt
drwxrwxrwx  4 mhicks     mhicks     4096 Aug  1 13:09 projects
drwxrwxr-x  3 mhicks     mhicks     4096 Jul 21 19:23 raspi
drwxrwxr-x  2 mhicks     mhicks     4096 Jul 21 17:03 RasPi_Part
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Samba instead of NFS when sharing files to windows. You can see what UID nobody is with `id nobody`

Comment: yes, that is what we were using at my work.  We are unsure, but there are issues with the internal network and many of us can't connect to our samba shares, even though they were working just a few days ago.  So, we wanted to try this approach to get the team moving again.

Comment: So instead of fixing something that was previously working, you decided to switch to something else? Maybe try SSHFS temporarily while you fix Samba.

Comment: according to my IT dept it is something going on internally and they are working on it.  So yes, we tried NFS just so we could get moving again until resolved. yes, no ideal, but better than nothing. I haven't heard of SSHFS before.  I can look into later, but I am hoping someone might see something obvious with the NFS.  I am not Linux expert and has taken me many hours to get this far with NFS.

Comment: Windows + NFS has never been very good